# how to convert the php file in to pdf file

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

I want to  convert the php file into pdf file, i don't know how to convert it. can any one help me?

Comment: More information please. You could just open the PHP file in a text editor, hit "print", and send it to a PDF printer (e.g. CutePDF). But I hardly believe this is what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you actually need "converting". If you want to create a PDF from PHP then there are of lots of libraries to allow you to do it. You can also build a HTML page and have that convert to a PDF too. Here are a couple to take a look at

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

http://www.fpdf.org/

Answer (score 2):

from what you described I understood that you want to convert a php file to a pdf file

to do that:

first install a virtual printer that handles pdf (for example, install adobe reader - it's free, it will automatically install an "Adobe PDF" printer)

then open the file in any editor and do a print, but from the printers dialog, select the "Adobe PDF" printer. it will save your file as a pdf

if you open the php file in an editor that supports source formatting (coloring etc) like Notepad++ for example, printing it to pdf will keep the formatting

Comment: Nothing like a literal answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through a shellcommand with [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). This can allow you to get the html printed from the php to be converted into a pdf which then can be downloaded (or displayed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.freepdfconvert.com/ to convert it online to pdf but you must save the .php file as .txt first.