# How to create a PDF file with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

I am working with my new project. I want to generate a new PDF file with the help of PHP code.

How can I do this? Do you any have any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more clear: you need to create a PDF using PHP, starting from what?

Comment: And how is this not a duplicate of [your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655941/how-to-convert-the-php-file-in-to-pdf-file) from two days ago???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try free libraries like [fPdf](http://www.fpdf.org/)

> FPDF is a PHP class which allows to
>   generate PDF files with pure PHP, that
>   is to say without using the PDFlib
>   library. F from FPDF stands for Free:
>   you may use it for any kind of usage
>   and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: hi my question is  wanna to create a new pdf file with the help core PHP code.. can you show me any demo.

Comment: I don't know that did you mean with 'core' but here is an demo, powered by fpdf http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto1.htm

Comment: i visited  that  demo could you understand what im telling i want to generate a new pdf file with the help of php code

Comment: Yep i understood and the page shows that too. It's php and creating a pdf file. Not enough?

Answer (score 3):

Look into [Zend_PDF](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) from Zend Framework - it allows you to create/manipulate PDFs.

Comment: can't do with php.. is there any need for use zend frame work

Comment: @magna with default PHP - no, you need either a library (one of which is Zend_PDF) or an extension - e.g. http://us2.php.net/pdf

Answer (score 3):

Use Zend_PDF I guess.

Check the documentation here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html

It's the best PDF generator for PHP IMO.