# how can i make the horizontal pdf file

Tags: php, pdf

hi guys how can i make a harizontal pdf file by using php.i created for the register form(name ,email, street,city country) can any one say some ideas.

thanks in adv

Comment: Please start asking better, more detailed questions with more context. What are you trying to do using what technology? Where are you stuck?Your update isn't helping either.

Comment: how is javascrot related to pdf creation?

Comment: You have already asked numerous equally hazy questions about the same topic, and received tons of support and related links. How about working on them first, and come up with specific questions if there is something you don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to generate the PDF, or for converting HTML straight into a PDF - [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

Comment: The OP has asked that already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666171/how-to-create-a-pdf-file-with-php

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose you need to include a library of php after downloading it [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)
And this is just an example to use fpdf library.

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF('l','mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'NAME');
$pdf->Cell(40,30,'EMAIL');
$pdf->Cell(40,50,'STREET');
$pdf->Cell(40,70,'CITY');
$pdf->Cell(40,100,'COUNTRY');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```