# Generate pdf report from sql database

Tags: php, sql, pdf

I have written an app for an ipad that once used sends data to an sql server. I can access this data using a web page, currently using php but this is not fixed, and I would like to be able to then click a button on the web page and generate a pdf report from the data in the sql database.

I am not really sure where to start looking so any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you start by making it work with an HTML page so you get the program flow right, then look at something like http://www.tcpdf.org/ and simply replace the portion of the code that generates the HTML report with something that generates a PDF report instead, which you can then send as a download to the client using the appropriate `header()`s

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create PDF files using PHP MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353927/how-to-create-pdf-files-using-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of libraries available.

http://www.fpdf.org/

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Google it you can get lot more. Personally i have used fpdf.Its little bit difficult to implement but flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve de data you want to show from de database first and then create the .pdf file using a class like FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/) or similar. *You can easily find it in google.

Answer (score 0):

You wish to generate a PDF, you got some options:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php Never used this
2. http://www.fpdf.org/ I used this one myself, works nice :)

And probably you'll be able to find loads more if you Google search for "PHP PDF library"