# PHP How to create a pdf and add images to it

Tags: php, pdf, gd, tcpdf, fpdf

How would I go about creating a pdf and then adding images to it (some images linked to externals sites)

Images that fit together (nospaces) in the exact inner size of a pdf

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYrVyg  so like this but in a pdf

CSS

```
#box{
    padding:40px; 
    border: 1px #ddd solid; 
    width:595px; 
    height:842px; 
    margin:10px auto;
}

img{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    /*margin-top: -4px;
    font-size: 0;*/
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="box">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WeMD1N4.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vurnlun.png">
    <a href="#" title="External link"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1Tb0RC2.png"></a>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LDaSHyq.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xlkjUDr.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Exlc6Mx.png">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KSWIxgz.png">
</div>
```

Thanks for you time and knowledge, it is very much appreciated!

Comment: You're going to need a PDF class.

Comment: You can read this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/4666184

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create PDF off HTML/CSS, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is your friend :-)